# meaning: "maybe next time"

Tags: vocabulary

‘*Maybe*’ and ‘*perhaps*’ are interpreted in [a Korean dictionary](http://www.doosandonga.com/shopping/malls/product_view.html?product_id=17246) as “*(used to ask or suggest something politely) if your situation permits, if it is possible* - [my interpretations]” This could be make sense in my own language, and the two words can be interpreted as one Korean word, '가능하시면' (I'm not sure, but this can be equivalent to *possibly* or *if possible*) .’

> A: Can you go shopping with me tomorrow?
>   B: I’m sorry. I have to visit my aunt.
>   A: Okay. ***Maybe*** next time.   (From the Korean education radio, EBS)

In this case, does ‘*maybe*’ have the meaning as interpreted in the dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usage is something like what your dictionary says.

I think the best way to explain it here is that "maybe" in this context is a softener. It makes the statement sound less emphatic, less like a command and more like a suggestion. "Maybe next time" is making an indefinite suggestion rather than definite plans, or even a more strongly voiced demand. It's hard to say that "Okay. Next time" would not also be a suggestion in this context, but "Maybe" makes it less demanding of one, and in other contexts, "Next time" could be seen as a promise or a threat, e.g.:

> A: Did you bring back the book I loaned you?
>   B: No, I'm sorry.
>   A: [Maybe] Next time.

With "Maybe" this is pretty clearly a request, not a demand; but without "Maybe" and with the right tone of voice, "Next time" could be a more emphatic demand that suggests the person will be upset if it isn't satisfied.